# How Do I Insert This Menu Into My Blogger Blog

Tags: html, css

I was searching for menus that could suit my blogger blog and luckily i came across one. But the problem is i don't know how to add the codes to the html. I no noting about codes, although i added the html as a gadget under HTML/JAVASCRIPT and the CSS above the        ]]> the the plugin code before  tag. The Codes are as follows..
The website i sawit from is http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/19/responsive-multi-level-menu/

HTML

```
<div id="dl-menu" class="dl-menuwrapper">
    <button class="dl-trigger">Open Menu</button>
    <ul class="dl-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Item 1</a>
            <ul class="dl-submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Sub-Item 4</a>
                    <ul class="dl-submenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-Sub-Item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-Sub-Item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-Sub-Item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><!-- ... --></li>
                <!-- ... -->
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><!-- ... --></li>
        <li><!-- ... --></li>
        <!-- ... -->
    </ul>
</div><!-- /dl-menuwrapper -->
```

CSS

```
.dl-menu.dl-animate-out-1 {
animation: MenuAnimOut1 0.4s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes MenuAnimOut1 {
50% {
    transform: translateZ(-250px) rotateY(30deg);
}
75% {
    transform: translateZ(-372.5px) rotateY(15deg);
    opacity: .5;
}
100% {
    transform: translateZ(-500px) rotateY(0deg);
    opacity: 0;
}
}

.dl-menu.dl-animate-in-1 {
animation: MenuAnimIn1 0.3s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes MenuAnimIn1 {
0% {
    transform: translateZ(-500px) rotateY(0deg);
    opacity: 0;
}
20% {
    transform: translateZ(-250px) rotateY(30deg);
    opacity: 0.5;
}
100% {
    transform: translateZ(0px) rotateY(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
}
}
```

A PLUGIN

```
$( '#dl-menu' ).dlmenu({
    animationClasses : { classin : 'animation-class-name', classout : 'animation-class-name' }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have put the HTML and CSS at right place. Now the plugin code is a jQuery code so you make sure you've jQuery in your blog and then add your plugin code above `</head>` like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$( '#dl-menu' ).dlmenu({
    animationClasses : { classin : 'animation-class-name', classout : 'animation-class-name' }
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To better specify your Mohammad Hamza's answer, the files need to be put in your `<head> </head>` tag. CSS should be first in order, before any .js files.

The css file you need, by the looks of the plugin, is `component.css`. The default.css file has a comment saying it's only the developer's demo styling, so ignore that file. Also, the CSS you have in your example, you don't need to put anywhere. That specific animation CSS, is also included in component.css

Then after that, include the `fonts` folder. These include an icon-font, made using the web app [Icomoon](http://icomoon.io). Last, you'll need the files in the `js` folder.

So inside your `<head>` it should look like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css">
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dlmenu.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps, and clarifies.